# Mapping Positional Arguments to Key Word Arguments

Tags: python

Is there a clean way to map positional arguments to key word arguments for a function that you are about to call?

For example, I am about to call the function below

`def test(a, b=None, c=None):`

and I will pass in

`test(*args, **kwargs)`

I know that `a` will receive `1`.

Is there a generic way to map `*args` to `{a: 1}` before it is passed into the function?

This would allow me to just use the `**kwargs` to determine which arguments have been passed in.

Comment: You don't have `args` *or* `kwargs`; you have *explicitly named* parameters. If you want to see if `b` was provided, use `if b is None:`.

Comment: Sorry let me refine my question; realized that parts of it were not clear.

Comment: Why does it matter how the parameters are passed in? Once inside the function, it's easy to tell which you received. Could you give some more context?

Comment: This can be done with `inspect.getargspec(test)`. Your request is really weird though, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it's an example of how to use `inspect.getargspec()`:

```
import inspect

def _call_fn(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(fn)
    _args = []
    _kw = {}
    _argspec_args = argspec.args[:]

    if args:
        # pass positional parameters given to us through
        _args += list(args)
        # skip the parameters we've matched
        _argspec_args = _argspec_args[len(args):]

    for argname in _argspec_args:
        if argname in kwargs:
            _args.append(kwargs.pop(argname))
        else:
            raise TypeError("%s expected parameter %s" % (fn.__name__, argname))

    if argspec.keywords is not None and kwargs:
        _kw.update(kwargs)

    # print _args, _kw
    return fn(*_args, **_kw)


def f(a, b, c, d):
    print a, b, c, d
```

it will match arguments given to arguments needed, so that you can provide extra arguments without causing a `TypeError`

```
_call_fn(f, 1, 2, d=2, c=3, b=4, q=42)
```

positional args have preference, so the above will print `1 2 3 2` (`1 2` from the first two arguments, `3` from `c=3`, `2` from `d=2`.  `b=4` and `q=42` will be discarded).